# Compare two Xcode build settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I have a project where I use two build settings predominantly. Unfortunately today something went wrong. One compiles and the other doesn't. How can I compare the two build settings in XCode to see what the differences are?

(For those interested, the error I get in one build is

```
jump to case label crosses initialization of 'const char* selectorName'
```

if you know what this means I'll be very grateful
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably declare a variable inside a case without wrapping it all in a brace:

```
case foo:
    const char* selectorName;
    // ...
    break;
```

Should be:

```
case foo: {
    const char* selectorName;
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your project configuration is stored in the directory (package) of:

YourAppName.xcodeproj

Open up terminal and cd into that directory.  You'll find some .plist format files:

project.pbxproj
username.pbxuser

You can do a diff on these files with your other project.  But you probably have issues with your source code in reality.  Do you have a switch case you are using?  Do you declare any variables in the switch?  If so, are you using brackets, {}?

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 and Xcode 13 if it's a scenario with multiple targets within the same project you can just <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> the targets you want to compare and enable **Levels** in the filter bar.

(see also https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/02/01/comparing-xcode-target-build-settings/)