# Pinterest Linker Error when added through CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, pinterest

1)I have did all steps given at Pinterest developer site [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/)

2)This is my pod file

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
     platform :ios, ‘7.0’
    # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
    # use_frameworks!

    target 'xyz.com' do
    pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
    end
   target 'xyz.comTests' do

    end
```

3)When I run **without** #import "PDKPin.h" & following code

```
[PDKPin pinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
                       link:[NSURL URLWithString:shareUrl]
         suggestedBoardName:@""
                       note:productName
                withSuccess:^
     {
         NSLog(@"Succesful to pin");

     }
                 andFailure:^(NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Failed to pin");
     }];
```

**it runs without error**

4)But when I add the above code it gives linker error

[image]

> Edit: I have tried it in blank project it works fine. But I am unable
>   to figure out what all the dependencies still there in old project.

Comment: I think @BraveS answer in here may can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: As I am using pods I don't think I need to add it explicitly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After a long search & tries** 
I have found the following solution

1. I have changed the target's build settings in
   the other linker flags section.
   I have added the flag **$(inherited)** in other linker flags

[image]

Comment: That inherited should have been automatic (created by the `pod install` scripts). Try this: make a backup-copy of your current `.xcworkspace`. Run `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`. This will create a new `.xcworkspace`, which should have the `$(inherited)` flag. Great you found it.

Answer (score 0):

## Start Fresh

Use Xcode 7.1+, create a **new** project, run `pod install`:

```
target 'SO-34633492' do
    pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
end
```

You probably have inconsistencies in your existing project ; while figuring out what is wrong may be enlightening, may I suggest starting on a clean slate.

**Must include headers**

You cannot compile your `.m` without including `#import <PDKPin.h>`:

> ~/SO-34633492/SO-34633492/ViewController.m:21:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'PDKPin'

This **does** work:

```
#import <PDKPin.h>
NSString * imageUrl = @"";
NSString * shareUrl = @"";
NSString * productName = @"";

[PDKPin pinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
                   link:[NSURL URLWithString:shareUrl]
     suggestedBoardName:@""
                   note:productName
            withSuccess:^
 {
     NSLog(@"Succesful to pin");
 }
             andFailure:^(NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Failed to pin");
 }];
```

---

**Things that may have gone wrong**

- Compare your projects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889730/218152
- Delete Derived data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32859942/218152
- Library not found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419234/218152
- Configuration error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509278/218152
- Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A218152+cocoapod

Comment: Thank you for reply . I already tried it in new project & It works smoothly.I forgot to mention it in my question. But,my problem is I have to implement it in existing project.Please suggest any workout.

Comment: This may be a different question. My answer shows that it works as designed. You may need to compare a fresh project to the existing broken one. +1 ?

Comment: Use the new project to compare the settings. You may have mismatch or conflicting settings. If you are not encountering errors with my answer, please consider √ and +1.

Comment: I have created new project and compared the settings.Not found any difference,Can you guide which settings may have the problems.You can specify it in answer

Comment: Thanks for supporting me .I found the solution for my issue.I have added in my answer.